# How to set you can't select after first selection of multiple-choice questions radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was building Multiple choice questions in a website with radio buttons, and then I check one of the four buttons. How to set the functionality that you can't select any of four radio buttons after first selection.

Comment: You can use disabled property, if a radio group is selected then make it disabled

Comment: Please add your HTML to illustrate the layout

Comment: I think your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116217/preventing-a-user-from-changing-the-state-of-a-radio-button

Comment: I think your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116217/preventing-a-user-from-changing-the-state-of-a-radio-button

Comment: Are you saying that the user cannot change their mind at all once they have clicked on one of the buttons? Will there be a way for them to undo this?